# AutoHide/Show Multiple Sheets based upon a cell value?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following VBA and it works great. It Auto/Hides or Auto/Shows perfectly.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("'Client Info'!D20")) Is Nothing Then
    If Range("'Client Info'!D20").Value > 0 And Not IsEmpty(Range("'Client Info'!D20")) Then
        Sheets("PLSHEET1").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Else
        Sheets("PLSHEET1").Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If End If End Sub
```

What I am trying to do now is have the Cell value in D20 Auto/Hide or Show two other additional sheets at the same time.

The following is what I am trying and running into trouble.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("'Client Info'!D20")) Is Nothing Then
    If Range("'Client Info'!D20").Value > 0 And Not IsEmpty(Range("'Client Info'!D20")) Then
        Sheets(Array("PULLSHEET1", "PULLSHEET2", "PULLSHEET3")).Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Else
        Sheets(Array("PULLSHEET1", "PULLSHEET2", "PULLSHEET3")).Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you just write three lines of the same code instead of an array, if the first example works perfectly and the array gives problems? Also the sheet names are different in your second example, but I guess, that is not the problem.

Comment: `Sheets(Array)` construction not exists. Application cannot understand syntax You invent.

Comment: My experience says using one single command line  can't hide/unhide few of the WKSts. The first method you are using is one of the ways. other I can suggest is to hide active sheet one by one but not  single command is, **ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden**

Comment: **#Klocksbass**, I can suggest you VBA code to Hide/Unhide some of the Sheets from WBK, like Sheet 3 & Sheet 5 or any combinations through TOGGLE COMMAND BUTTON. Just confirm through Comments.

Answer (score 0):

The `Sheets` collection only accepts an index argument for it's default (`Item`) method. You cannot pass an array to it. You need to loop over the items in the array and use them one by one.

The following shows how to do that:

```vb
'============================================================================================
' Module     : <in the "Client Info" sheet module>
' Version    : 0.1.0
' Part       : 1 of 1
' References : N/A
' Source     : https://superuser.com/a/1328507/763880
'============================================================================================
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("'Client Info'!D20")) Is Nothing Then
    Dim enumVisibility As Excel.XlSheetVisibility
    If Range("'Client Info'!D20").Value > 0 Then
      enumVisibility = xlSheetVisible
    Else
      enumVisibility = xlSheetHidden
    End If
    Dim varSheetName As Variant
    For Each varSheetName In Array("PULLSHEET1", "PULLSHEET2", "PULLSHEET3")
      Sheets(varSheetName).Visible = enumVisibility
    Next varSheetName
  End If
End Sub
```

Note that I have removed the redundant `And Not IsEmpty(Range("'Client Info'!D20"))`.

You can also see that I have used a variable to store the required visibility and moved the actual setting of it to after the `If` statement. This way, only one loop needs to be used instead of two.

If the sheet names all contain a base name with a number suffix, a better loop would be:

```vb
Dim lngSheetNumber As Long
For lngSheetNumber = 1 To 3
  Sheets("PULLSHEET" & lngSheetNumber).Visible = enumVisibility
Next lngSheetNumber
```

Comment: Thanks to all. Problem solved. BTW, robinCTS. Great idea with the loop with base name and suffix number.

Comment: @klocksbass Thanks. In case you're unaware, the recommended way to say thanks on Superuser is to "accept" the most helpful answer to your question (by clicking the grey tick at the top left of the answer), and, when you reach 15 reputation, to upvote all useful/good answers (including the accepted answer). Note that accepting an answer also rewards you with +2 rep. Taking the [Tour] will give you a better idea of how this site works. More details on accepting answers can be found [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: @klocksbass Oh, another useful tip for you - when you post code in a question, select the code and then click the `{}` icon (at the top of the question box) or press Ctrl+K. This will format the code as a code block.